# how to change the time in object in python?

Tags: python, python-2.7

I'm working on my code to change the 12 hours time in the object strings.

I need some help with my code because I have a bit of trouble with changing the 12 hours time in the object.

```
def GoLeft(self):

   if CurrentRow == 375:
       if self.channel_page >= 0:
          # Set the date and time row
          getTime1 = self.getControl(344)
          getTime2 = self.getControl(345)
          getTime3 = self.getControl(346)
          getTime3.setLabel(getTime2.getLabel())
          getTime2.setLabel(getTime1.getLabel())
          getTime1 = self.getControl(344).getLabel()
          hour = time.strftime("%I").lstrip('0')

          #Find the time for each clock to change the text
          if getTime1 == '12:00AM':
             self.getControl(344).setLabel('11:30AM')
          elif getTime1 == '12:30AM':
             self.getControl(344).setLabel('12:00AM')
          elif getTime1 == '1:00AM':
             self.getControl(344).setLabel('12:30AM')
          elif getTime1 == '1:30AM':
             self.getControl(344).setLabel('1:00AM')
          elif getTime1 == '2:00AM':
             self.getControl(344).setLabel('1:30AM')
          elif getTime1 == '2:30AM':
             self.getControl(344).setLabel('2:00AM')
          elif getTime1 == '3:00AM':
             self.getControl(344).setLabel('2:30AM')
          elif getTime1 == '3:30AM':
             self.getControl(344).setLabel('3:00AM')
          elif getTime1 == '4:00AM':
             self.getControl(344).setLabel('3:30AM')
          elif getTime1 == '4:30AM':
             self.getControl(344).setLabel('4:00AM')
          elif getTime1 == '5:00AM':
             self.getControl(344).setLabel('4:30AM')
          elif getTime1 == '5:30AM':
             self.getControl(344).setLabel('5:00AM')
          elif getTime1 == '6:00AM':
             self.getControl(344).setLabel('5:30AM')
          elif getTime1 == '6:30AM':
             self.getControl(344).setLabel('6:00AM')
          elif getTime1 == '7:00AM':
             self.getControl(344).setLabel('6:30AM')
          elif getTime1 == '7:30AM':
             self.getControl(344).setLabel('7:00AM')
          elif getTime1 == '8:00AM':
             self.getControl(344).setLabel('7:30AM')
          elif getTime1 == '8:30AM':
             self.getControl(344).setLabel('8:00AM')
          elif getTime1 == '9:00AM':
             self.getControl(344).setLabel('8:30AM')
          elif getTime1 == '9:30AM':
             self.getControl(344).setLabel('9:00AM')
          elif getTime1 == '10:00AM':
             self.getControl(344).setLabel('9:30AM')
          elif getTime1 == '10:30AM':
             self.getControl(344).setLabel('10:00AM')
          elif getTime1 == '11:00AM':
             self.getControl(344).setLabel('10:30AM')
          elif getTime1 == '11:30AM':
             self.getControl(344).setLabel('11:00AM')
          elif getTime1 == '12:00PM':
             self.getControl(344).setLabel('11:30AM')
          elif getTime1 == '12:30PM':
             self.getControl(344).setLabel('12:00PM')
          elif getTime1 == '1:00PM':
             self.getControl(344).setLabel('12:30AM')
          elif getTime1 == '1:30PM':
             self.getControl(344).setLabel('1:00PM')
          elif getTime1 == '2:00PM':
             self.getControl(344).setLabel('1:30PM')
          elif getTime1 == '2:30PM':
             self.getControl(344).setLabel('2:00PM')
          elif getTime1 == '3:00PM':
             self.getControl(344).setLabel('2:30PM')
          elif getTime1 == '3:30PM':
             self.getControl(344).setLabel('3:00PM')
          elif getTime1 == '4:00PM':
             self.getControl(344).setLabel('3:30PM')
          elif getTime1 == '4:30PM':
             self.getControl(344).setLabel('4:00PM')
          elif getTime1 == '5:00PM':
             self.getControl(344).setLabel('4:30PM')
          elif getTime1 == '5:30PM':
             self.getControl(344).setLabel('5:00PM')
          elif getTime1 == '6:00PM':
             self.getControl(344).setLabel('5:30PM')
          elif getTime1 == '6:30PM':
             self.getControl(344).setLabel('6:00PM')
          elif getTime1 == '7:00PM':
             self.getControl(344).setLabel('6:30PM')
          elif getTime1 == '7:30PM':
             self.getControl(344).setLabel('7:00PM')
          elif getTime1 == '8:00PM':
             self.getControl(344).setLabel('7:30PM')
          elif getTime1 == '8:30PM':
             self.getControl(344).setLabel('8:00PM')
          elif getTime1 == '9:00PM':
             self.getControl(344).setLabel('8:30PM')
          elif getTime1 == '9:30PM':
             self.getControl(344).setLabel('9:00PM')
          elif getTime1 == '10:00PM':
             self.getControl(344).setLabel('9:30PM')
          elif getTime1 == '10:30PM':
             self.getControl(344).setLabel('10:00PM')
          elif getTime1 == '11:00PM':
             self.getControl(344).setLabel('10:30PM')
          elif getTime1 == '11:30PM':
              self.getControl(344).setLabel('11:00PM')
```

It will let me to change the time to 30 mins back, e.g: from `1:30AM` to `1:00AM`. When I have the time `1:00AM`, it will not find the strings of `1:00AM` to change it to `12:30PM`. The reason for this is because I have two different type of `AM` and `PM`.

Can you please show me an example of how can I find the time between AM and PM before changing the strings in the object to the time that I actually want?

Comment: You really need to use some loops and data structures there.

Comment: @TigerhawkT3 thank you for your advice, could you please show me an example code that i should use some loops and data structures?

Comment: You overwrite `getTime1` in your function. Which value did you intend to set it to?

Comment: @Paul Rooney: I'm trying to set the value from `1:00AM` or whatever it say in the getTime object strings. Is that possible to set the value from `1:00AM` to `12:30PM` and from `1:00AM` to `12:30AM`?

Answer (score 3):

You can substract the half hour like this:

```
from datetime import timedelta
import datetime
getTime1 = "12:00AM"
t = datetime.datetime.strptime(getTime1, "%I:%M%p")
time_half_hour_before = (t-timedelta(days=-1, minutes=30)).strftime("%I:%M%p")
print time_half_hour_before
```

which prints:

```
11:30PM
```

Comment: thank you, when i try this: `t = datetime.datetime.strptime(getTime1, "%I:%M%p")` it give me the error `TypeError: attribute of type 'NoneType' is not callable`. do you have any idea why i recieved the error?

Comment: Check the imports carefully. Datetime is kind of a mess in python. You need to import datetime, not from datetime import datetime or it will fail.

Comment: i'm using `import datetime` and i still get the same here, do you know why?

Comment: here is what i'm using `getTime1 = getTime2.getLabel()
                     t = datetime.datetime.strptime(getTime1, "%I:%M%p")
                     time_half_hour_before = (t.datetime(days=-1, minutes=30)).strftime("%I:%M%p")
                     print time_half_hour_before`

Comment: i'm waiting for your answer, please answer it.

Comment: I heared that more people had a problem with the import with datetime. Have a look here, maybe one of these solutions work for you: http://forum.kodi.tv/showthread.php?tid=112916

Comment: Then I have no idea where that Nonetype problem could come from.